# What if my bahncard does not show up automatically on app but I don't have bahncard number?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

I bought trial bahncard for 3 months on online, but it seems like I couldn't get the physical card because I'm not sure if it will be delivered before my trip to Germany.
I know I can use the temporary PDF or the digital card on app, the problem is my app doesn't show the bahncard somehow. My friend's temporary card have show up on her app so she might just wait until the temporary card is given the card number after the production(I read it somewhere). But I have no way to check and I need to register on app with the bahncard number which I don't have.
I need to use the card after the validity of PDF and cancel the renewal. DB email services keep not replying to my email. What should I do?

Comment: https://www.bahn.com/en/view/home/info/contact.shtml

Comment: In the DB Navigator app, you can log in with your DB account, i.e. mail address and password. The BahnCard should show up then.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you should have received the card number via mail. First I would recheck that, If there really is no mail with your card number I would contact the DB via chat. That is free and you can get your response immediately. You can find it here:

[DB - Chat](http://www.bahn.de/msz-chat)

Otherwise you have to contact them via telephone:

[DB - Telephone Contact](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/hilfe/bahn_de/telefon.shtml?dbkanal_007=L01_S01_D001_KIN0057_-_KONTAKT-NEU-TELEFON_LZ01)